# Rails fixtures don't seem to store values in Globalize3 translation tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, fixtures, globalize3

I have a Rails 3.2.7 project using Globalize3 0.3.0 
It seems that if you make a fixture for a model with an attribute that is translated with Globalize3, the fixture will populate the model's table in the database, but not the translation table used by Globalize3. 
As a result, if you use the model in a unit test, the value for the translated attribute is not found. If this attribute has a presence validation rule, then this makes the model invalid.
I have a work around, which consists of using a global setup for the unit tests, explicitly setting the translated attributes of the fixture models. But that's not a good solution. 
Is there any way to fix this problem?